# Exclude compiling mockable Android jar

Tags: android-studio

I noticed that my android studio automatically adds a grade task :mockableAndroidJar. Is there a way to exclude this task from automatically happening.

I want to do this in hope that it might speed up the Gradle build step.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude that task from running when doing a Gradle build as follows:

```
gradle build -x mockableAndroidJar
```